# Implementing a special type of array class in Python feasibility

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hash

A special array class where you can update and lookup a value and it returns the earliest index that the value exists in the array. And u can update given an index and a value.

Is it possible to do both operations in O(1)?

I was trying this, but I could only get look up to be O(1) using two hashmaps. No matter what I did, I could not get update to be O(1).

Comment: Why does updating a `dict` fail to be O(1)?

Comment: I mean the update() operation for this new Array class fails to be O(1), as you have to potentially look for the next occurrence of the character that used to be at position i, after doing update(i, "a').

Comment: I don't there's currently such implementation at the moment, the closest I can think of is the [LRU cache](https://realpython.com/lru-cache-python/) implementation which is key-value pair structure with read, write in O(1) but if trying to apply it to array, the next indices needed to be updated for insertion

Answer (score 0):

The best that I can do is to have a random operation on average be `O(1)`. And worst case, `O(log(n))`.

I get that by making each value be a dict to a heap of where that value may be found, and having a separate dict from index to value, and position of the entry in the heap. All of the dict operations are `O(1)`. And the heap operation will be `O(log(size of heap))` for operations near the start of the array, and an average of `O(1)` for a random position in the array.

That's because 1/2 of the time with a heap you need 1 operation, 1/4 of the time you need 2, 1/8 of the time you need three, and so on. So the most you need is `O(log(size of heap))`. Slicing that pattern differently, all of the time you need at least 1 operation, 1/2of the time you need a second, 1/4 of the time you need a third, and so on. So the expected number of operations is:

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 2
```

Which is `O(1)`.